# Pass a Variable From Within "if" Block to Another PHP File

Tags: php

a complete PHP noobe here.
I am trying to separate my view and my model. When I try to read from the database in the model and call the variable that holds the results in the view (with include() function) I get either variable not defined error or empty value.
So the View.php looks something like:

**View.php**

```
<?php include("Model.php")?> 
<p id="p1"><?php echo $var ?> </p>
```

**Model.php** 
(without declaring $var outside the "if" block):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // reading from database
    $var = result of the query

}
```

** this option yields error $var is not defined.

**Model.php** 
($var is declared and initialized  outside the "if" block):

```
$var = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // reading from database
    $var = result of the query

}
```

** this option yields echoing empty page.

**Model.php** 
(with declaring $var as global outside the "if" block):
    :

```
global $var;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // reading from database
    $var = result of the query

}
```

** this option yields echoing empty page as well.

**EDIT**
The form that sends the request is located in View.php (so i'm expecting to receive the results on the same page where the form is...)

```
<form action="Model.php", method="post">
```

**EDIT 2**
The form lives in **view.php** (and that's also where I expect to show the results)

```
<form action="Model.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="entername">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

The only way I managed to get it work was by merging the two files into one and than I can call variables freely between the "model" section of the file and "view" section.

I would be thankful for any insight as to how to solve this.

Comment: do you send post request?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is it's not going into the `if` part, not that you can't access the variable. So are you testing the page by sending POST variables? (you can't do this in the browser without posting a form). For testing you could change it to $_GET rather than $_POST and use a querystring instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I didn't include the form in my code, but I do have a form with `action="Model.php"`  and `method="post"`

Comment: `$_POST['submit']` would also only be set if your form had a control with `name="submit"`?  You can inspect your POST data in the browser in its Dev Tools (usually by pressing F12) and looking at what your browser sent in the Dev Tools' Network tab.

Comment: If you want to detect a HTTP POST in PHP, then it's something like `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')`

Comment: do var_dump($_POST); before your if condition and check if you are getting 'submit' in it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I do have `<input type="text" name = "name">` and `<input type='submit' name='submit'>` in my form. may the problem be that I have both the form and the include() on the same file? I will check the in dev tools for sure.

Comment: you should call `view.php` instead `action="Model.php"` aren't you?

Comment: Alex, what do you mean? the form resides in view.php (and that is also where the results should be displayed). Thanks.

Comment: Away from your problem, using global variables and passing variables cross php files will make your software very difficult to maintain later. Instead build and use classes and call functions, also invest more time in understanding and applying OOP, this will save you a lot of time later ;)

Comment: I mean that correct action url is `action="View.php"`

Comment: I guess you should share all your html especially the from part

Comment: What do you want `$var` to be if this condition is not true `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` ?

Comment: If you are posting to Model.php, how do you include View.php in order to display the result?  State exists within PHP variables only for the lifetime of the request.

Comment: @Lee Kowalkowski, are you suggesting that I should include(view.php) as part of the "if" block in Model.php? (as opposed to what I have now which is the other way around: include(Model.php) in View.php...). I should will that!

Comment: Nope, I think Alex's answer is correct.  Your model is a dependency of your view, in MVC terms, you don't expose models directly, they're there to handle business logic/rules, so you would never have a browser request a model like that.  Your View.php is acting like both controller and view right now (which is actually not that terrible an approach for a small PHP system).

Comment: cool, I'll check it later today when I get home and report back how @Alex's suggestion plays out. Thanks guys, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your action url in `View.php` it should be

```
<form action="View.php" method="post">
```

since you have your `Model.php` included `include("Model.php")` in `View.php`

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much Alex. I pulled my hairs out last night trying to figure that out. Thank you also to @Lee Kowalkowski for bringing up the intermediate control concept. I've read about it and will try to implement this and see how it'll go.